# fseek/fsetpos may discard stream buffer?

Tags: c, posix

In the C standard for fopen regarding files opened in update mode (C11 7.21.5.3/7), output followed by input requires an intervening call to fflush or a file positioning function (fseek, fsetpos, or rewind).  However, none of the file positioning functions are required to do anything regarding the output buffer.

The POSIX standard maintains the same requirement for [fopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) and update mode.  As with the C standard, [fsetpos](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fsetpos.html) is not required to do anything with the output buffer.  However, [fseek](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fseek.html) is required to write the buffer to file.

In the case of both C and POSIX, a conforming implementation seems free to discard the write buffer when fsetpos is called, and C seems to allow fseek to do the same.  My first question is whether I've missed something relevant in the standards.  The implication here is that a portable application must call fflush (or fseek/rewind in the case of POSIX) to ensure buffered output is actually written before switching from output to input.

Obviously, discarding the write buffer goes against the intent of all of the write functions, and I'm not aware of any implementation that does this or anything comparably counter-intuitive.  I'm also aware of my limited awareness, so my second question is whether there are any conforming implementations that don't ensure the buffered content eventually gets written in the proper place.

For context, the GNU documentation maintains the same requirement for [fopen](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-Streams.html) and update mode.  As with C and POSIX, [fsetpos](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Portable-Positioning.html) says nothing about the output buffer, but my testing suggests my version does flush the buffer.  However, [fseek](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Positioning.html) may either flush the buffer or remember enough about it to ensure its contents eventually get written properly.

**TL;DR:** Does C or POSIX disallow fsetpos from discarding the write buffer?  Are there implementations that do this?

**EDIT:** Nobody has yet presented credible evidence that either standard prohibits fsetpos from discarding the write buffer.  Similarly, nobody has mentioned any implementations that do this.  However, this is not mentioned in the list of portability issues in the C standard (Annex J), suggesting it is an oversight and not an obscure portability concern.  Furthermore, as mentioned by R.., there is no prohibition preventing completely unrelated functions from discarding buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C standard does not seem to explicitly prohibit `fsetpos` (or any other function) from discarding the buffer, which seems to be an arguably pedantic deficiency.  However, the C99 Rationale document (7.19.5.3) states that `fsetpos`, `fseek`, `rewind`, and `fflush` "assure that the I/O buffer has been flushed".  It's not clear why such text was not included in the standard, although one could speculate about GNU and write-back caches and whether forcing disk I/O on seek operations is desirable.

In practice, this means that one should be able to assume writing, then seeking, then reading will return the expected data.  Given that at least one implementation (GNU) may not always flush when seeking, though, one should not assume the data will have reached the kernel (let alone the underlying device) without an explicit flush request.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything requiring the flush in the `fsetpos` case, beyond this remark in the *Errors* section (twice):

> or the *stream*'s buffer needed to be flushed,

This looks like an omission in POSIX.  Please file a clarification request in the [Austin Group issue tracker](http://austingroupbugs.net/).

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you mean by not seeing anything requiring the flush, and apologies if I've misinterpreted.  If you mean you don't see where POSIX requires it in fseek, then it states, "If the stream is writable and buffered data had not been written to the underlying file, fseek() shall cause the unwritten data to be written to the file."  There is not corresponding text regarding fsetpos.

Comment: If you mean you don't understand the implication that a portable application must fflush, then I'll try to clarify.  If a conforming implementation is allowed to discard the write buffer when seeking, then an application that assumes fsetpos will write the buffer will lose some output on this platform.

Comment: In any case, I'm not sure why fseek is required to flush and fsetpos is not.  Asking the Austin Group for clarification is my next step, if I don't get any good answers here.

Comment: Sorry, I for got to mention that my comment is about `fsetpos`, not `fseek`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you're getting that idea from. POSIX goes into a little bit more detail than the C standard about buffering behavior because it has to deal with interactions of stdio FILE streams with other means of accessing the same files. But there is nothing in the C standard that suggests the implementation is allowed to lose output when you call `fsetpos`. Logically the data has already been written.

Further, the specification (C11 7.21.9.3, ¶2) for `fsetpos` reads:

> If a read or write error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and fsetpos fails.

The only plausible reason a write error could occur is some sort of write operation, and the only plausible write operation is flushing pending output.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in the C standard prohibiting a conforming implementation of fsetpos from discarding the write buffer, seeking, and returning success.  The presence of text about write errors does not imply a requirement to write.  If an implementation chooses to write the buffer, then it must follow the quoted text when write errors are encountered.  I agree that most implementations make the effort to ensure the data in the buffers get written, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: @ov2k: The requirement to write is in the specification of the `fputc` function. Logically the write takes place at that point. Buffering is specified such that the underlying write can take place later, but there is no allowance that it be silently discarded. **As usual** the C standard is not rigorous in spelling this out, but this is how everything in the C standard is. The committee does not see it a productive use of time to correct lack of rigorousness unless it's not obvious what the intent is, and here it's completely obvious.

Comment: Note that, as far as I can tell, it's also possible that an implementation could partition its buffer to cover multiple parts of the file, so that writing out the buffer contents is not necessary at seek time. In that case the write error might be reported *later than the seek operation*, and the seek might succeed. But if the implementation is not capable of keeping the data written prior to the seek in its buffer after the seek succeeds, it must write it out, and it must report failure if that fails.

Comment: I'll accept that the C standard doesn't explicitly state that content can't be discarded (I couldn't find any such text either).  However, I do feel the standard is fairly careful about what exactly it does and does not allow.  Lots of errors arise because people assume the intent behind the standard is obvious, when it actually allows some (usually obscure) exceptions.  I find the situation even less clear because POSIX requires that `fseek` write but not `fsetpos`.  I find it safer to ask.

Comment: @ov2k: I think what you're seeing with POSIX is easily explained by `fseek` having been endowed with a large CX description covering interaction with file descriptors, whereas `fsetpos` mostly just mirrors the C text. But POSIX defers to C, and cannot mandate that an implementation be non-conforming to the C requirements. Moreover, I think you missed the text for `fsetpos`: *The fsetpos() function shall fail if, [CX> either the stream is unbuffered **or the stream's buffer needed to be flushed**, and the call to fsetpos() causes an underlying lseek() or write() to be invoked, and:...*

Comment: Like the C text for `fsetpos`, that part of the POSIX standard only specifies what should happen if an implementation chooses to write the buffer.  Neither standard requires that `fsetpos` write the buffer and neither standard seems to prohibit it from discarding the buffer.  The intent behind the disparity between POSIX's `fsetpos` and `fseek` is not at all clear.

Comment: @ov2k: No, it doesn't say "if the implementation chooses to write the buffer". It says "**shall fail** if...the stream's buffers **needed to be** flushed." If the implementation is capable of satisfying all other requirements without flushing buffers (e.g. if the buffers are tied to a specific location in the file and can be left to flush until later, after the seek) then they don't "need to be" flushed here. But if the implementation is incapable of this, they "need to be flushed", and it **shall fail** if it can't do that.

Comment: As you pointed out, the bit you quoted only applies if the implementation decides the buffer needs to be flushed.  Discarding the buffer in `fsetpos` satisfies all other requirements I could find without ever needing to flush the buffer. The statement neither requires the buffer to be written nor prohibits the buffer from being discarded.

Comment: @ov2k: It can't "decide" this unless it has an alternate method to preserve the requirements. Discarding the buffer **does not satisfy the requirements**. You're being intentionally obtuse and I'm about to the point of just downvoting this question and stopping responding.

Comment: You keep mentioning requirements, yet don't reference any such requirements.  The things you have referenced do not require that an implementation of `fsetpos` not discard the buffer.  I think you're reading meaning and intent in the standards that may be correct but are not explicitly stated and could use clarification.  I expect we'll continue to disagree about this.  Finally, please don't resort to name calling and petty threats.  You're better than that and it's not befitting somebody with your reputation.

Comment: @ov2k: 7.21.7.3 *The fputc function*, ¶2: " The fputc function writes the character specified by c (converted to an unsigned char) to the output stream pointed to by stream, at the position indicated by the associated file position indicator for the stream (if defined), and advances the indicator appropriately." That's all there is to it (all write operations are specified in terms of `fputc`). It does not go on to say "if the implementor decides they want to, they can subsequently decide to throw away this write at the time of `fsetpos`." ...

Comment: By your (completely wrong) line of reasoning, a subsequent call to `strlen` elsewhere in the program could throw away the buffer for a stdio FILE "because there's nothing saying it can't". That's not how it works. Unless the standard specifically prescribes or allows a behavior that alters the value stored in objects, the contents of a file, etc. as a side effect of one of the interfaces it specifies, such alteration is not permitted and would be non-conforming if an implementation did it.

Comment: The absence of text in `fputc` permitting discarding the buffer is not a prohibition on such behavior. The `fputc` text explicitly refers to writing to the stream and makes no guarantee that the contents of the stream will reach the underlying device.  In particular, `abort` and `_Exit` are explicitly permitted to discard buffers, and they are consistent with the `fputc` text and not exceptions to it.

Comment: Regarding you statement about the behavior not specifically prescribed or allowed by the standard being not permitted, can you reference a relevant part of the standard?  I'm perfectly willing to accept that, if it is indeed part of the standard.

Comment: Your `strlen` example is good.  The standard does seem to allow `strlen` to discard stdio buffers, as there's nothing in the standard prohibiting it.  That's good evidence that this is not an exception made for some obscure implementation, which was the original point.

Comment: @ov2k: At this point I'm not sure whether you're trolling or really this ignorant of how to read a specification. There is no way to enumerate all possible wrong side effects that an interface is not permitted to have. Rather, all side effects observable within the scope of the language as specified that are not explicitly mandated or allowed as degrees of freedom to the implementation must be interpreted as disallowed.

Comment: The C standard is quite rigorous about leaving implementations free to do whatever they like as long as it does not conflict with any explicit requirements or prohibitions.  At the hardware level, there are many details that are not explicitly stated but which must be defined.  For example, implementations are free to use ASLR, even though it is not explicitly required, allowed, or prohibited.  The standard is written so that irrelevant things do not affect conformance.

Comment: As for enumerating prohibitions, you are correct; it is generally impossible.  It is much easier to describe the required behavior, which is what the C standard usually does.  I think it should be sufficient to say something simple like, "All content written to streams must be output to their respective devices on program termination through or as if through `exit`."

Comment: @ov2k: The specification for `exit` already says that any unflushed buffered data is written. It doesn't say "any unflushed buffered data except data that was written prior to `fsetpos` without calling `fflush` first."

Comment: Content not in the buffer is not buffered data.  Anything discarding by a call to a questionable implementation of `fsetpos` would not be "unwritten buffered data".

Comment: @ov2k: You're continuing to willfully misinterpret stuff - "buffered" obviously means "that was put in a buffer" and "unflushed" means "that hasn't been flushed yet". Data does not lose its status of having been put in a buffer just because you imagine some wrong implementation that discards it. If you're unwilling to accept obvious meanings like this, the C standard is not a document for you and you should put it down and consult language lawyers who understand how to read it.

Comment: We clearly have different interpretations on "buffered".  I read that to mean data currently in the buffer.  You seem to interpret that as data that was ever put in the buffer.  The standard seems to be silent as to how "buffered" should be interpreted.  I tire of this discussion, and will leave it at that.  You may continue to make baseless assertions and petty insults as you wish.